# Authorize.net DPM (SIM) Form Post Error

Tags: authorize.net

I am having some issues implementing Authorize.net DPM (Direct Post Method). When I try to submit the form I get a failure message, response reason code 92 (The gateway no longer supports the requested method of integration). The response DOES show the output from my relay url (which simply spits out the returned post data that is listed below in the RESPONSE).

**How can I form post directly to authorize.net and have it relay back to the page of my choice without throwing the error code 92?**

If I change [x_relay_response] = FALSE ; than the transaction works, though ofcourse, it doesn't utilize my relay_url.

The original REQUEST, RESPONSE and RESPONSE WITH X_RELAY_RESPONSE=FALSE are all below:

Thank you in advance for your help!

REQUEST

```
[payMethod] => creditcard
[payType] => VI
[x_card_num] => 4111111111111111
[x_first_name] => test 
[x_last_name] => test 
[x_exp_date] => 07/2015
[x_card_code] => 123
[x_po_num] => 
[x_login] => [REMOVED]
[x_version] => 3.1
[x_delim_char] => |
[x_delim_data] => TRUE
[x_encap_char] => ^
[x_type] => AUTH_ONLY
[x_method] => CC
[x_tran_key] => [REMOVED]
[x_relay_response] => TRUE
[x_relay_url] => [REMOVED - VERIFIED WHITE LISTED URL]
[x_description] => 183002153
[x_invoice_num] => 183002153
[x_amount] => 114
[x_address] => test address
[x_city] => Bethesda
[x_state] => CA
[x_zip] => 20817
[x_customer_ip] => 71.163.185.8
[x_relay_always] => TRUE
```

RESPONSE (correctly forwards to relay URL)

```
[fa] => ORDER.authNetRelay
[x_response_code] => 3
[x_response_reason_code] => 92
[x_response_reason_text] => The gateway no longer supports the requested method of integration.
[x_avs_code] => P
[x_auth_code] => 
[x_trans_id] => 0
[x_method] => CC
[x_card_type] => 
[x_account_number] => 
[x_first_name] => 
[x_last_name] => 
[x_company] => 
[x_address] => 
[x_city] => 
[x_state] => 
[x_zip] => 
[x_country] => 
[x_phone] => 
[x_fax] => 
[x_email] => 
[x_invoice_num] => 
[x_description] => 
[x_type] => auth_only
[x_cust_id] => 
[x_ship_to_first_name] => 
[x_ship_to_last_name] => 
[x_ship_to_company] => 
[x_ship_to_address] => 
[x_ship_to_city] => 
[x_ship_to_state] => 
[x_ship_to_zip] => 
[x_ship_to_country] => 
[x_amount] => 114.00
[x_tax] => 0.00
[x_duty] => 0.00
[x_freight] => 0.00
[x_tax_exempt] => FALSE
[x_po_num] => 
[x_MD5_Hash] => [REMOVED]
[x_cvv2_resp_code] => 
[x_cavv_response] => 
[x_test_request] => false
[payMethod] => creditcard
[payType] => VI
```

RESPONSE WITH [x_relay_response] = FALSE: (note all other REQUEST data is identical)

^2^|^1^|^2^|^This transaction has been declined.^|^000000^|^U^|^7073317211^|^183002153^|^183002153^|^114.00^|^CC^|^auth_only^|^^|^test^|^test^|^^|^test address^|^Bethesda^|^CA^|^20817^|^^|^^|^^|^^|^^|^^|^^|^^|^^|^^|^^|^^|^^|^^|^^|^^|^^|^[REMOVED]^|^P^|^^|^^|^^|^^|^^|^^|^^|^^|^^|^^|^^|^XXXX1111^|^Visa^|^^|^^|^^|^^|^^|^^|^^|^^|^^|^^|^^|^^|^^|^^|^^|^^|^creditcard^|^VI^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue: I should have been passing the fingerprint data instead of the transaction key.

Remove:

- x_trans_key

Add:

- x_fp_hash
- x_fp_sequence
- x_fp_timestamp

the fingerprint (x_fp_...) data is generated as per:
http://developer.authorize.net/guides/SIM/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm#href=SIM_Submitting_transactions.06.3.html

Also: when using relay the data returned as POST data in the header NOT delimited string content, so the following fields can now be omitted as well:

- x_delim_char
- x_delim_data
- x_encp_char

Comment: The link is now invalid.

Comment: The info for computing those values is now in this document: http://www.authorize.net/content/dam/authorize/documents/SIM_guide.pdf